# Returning a Bool in a function

Tags: swift, function, if-statement, boolean

I'm getting the error "missing return in function expected to return 'Bool'" but I can't figure out why.

```
func isPrime(_ number: Int) -> Bool {
   for primeDivisors in 2..<number {
       if number % primeDivisors == 0 {
           return true
       } else {
           return false
       }
   }
}

isPrime(13)
```

Comment: If you call `isPrime(1)` your `for` loop will never execute and the function will never hit a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prime checker is incorrect, because the very first iteration of the loop returns a value. You have to go through the entire loop before deciding that the number is prime.

```
func isPrime(_ number: Int) -> Bool {
    for primeDivisors in 2..<number {
        if number % primeDivisors == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Note that this code is inefficient, because it continues checking divisibility more times than it is necessary: you can stop checking upon reaching square root of `number`.

Comment: It's important to note that your `false` and `true` conditions are correct; OP's conditions are the *opposite* of what they should have been.

Comment: @NRitH That's definitely true - that's why I switched them around. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining because not all code paths end up returning something. What happens if `number` is less than 2? Then your `for` loop, and the return statements inside it, will never be called, and there's no `return` that happens after the `for` loop finishes.